# Extra bullet item showing at the beginning of an html unordered list in IE8

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, html-lists

Throughout my site I am seeing an extra, empty bullet at the beginning of every unordered list `<ul>` in IE8, but not Firefox.

I validated the page using the W3C validator service and have no HTML errors.  If I switch to "Compatibility" mode in IE8, then the extra bullet point disappears.

Has anyone encountered this?  What's the problem?

Comment: Can you show us some code from the site? perhaps you could host a small html page with a single unordered list where this problem exists somewhere.

Comment: <p>Create your account:
   <ul><li>You must complete the application</li>
  </ul>
  </p>  - It's the simplest possible list.  I have the problem everywhere throughout the site, on nested ULs and on simple ones like this.  It's not the HTML.

Comment: So you think its in your CSS? What if you remove the outer P tags? Did you remove all your CSS stylesheets? Did you validate your css?

Comment: Justin, thank you! Commenting out the CSS fixed the problem.  Turns out it was ul{display: list-item;} causing the issue.  Since I don't really need this CSS property set, I simply commented it out.

Comment: Ok I provided an answer, please mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error as our conversation in the comments proved, is caused by the css line `ul{display: list-item;}`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and the problem was with my HTML.

```
<ul>
<li><b>notice bold tag to left.</li>
<li>this is the second list item.</li>
<li>notice the end bold tag on the right.</b></li>
</ul>
```

In my case, moving the `</b>` outside of the `</li>` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I forgot to close the list with `</li>`. It was fixed by adding the closing tag.